# SQLite database doesn't work with android while on windows it works perfectly fine

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to add database to my android project, other databases that are on phone seem to work fine. When i tried mine, utility i try to view my db, reports that database image is malformed and it can't execute query to list tables and views.

I tried to copy db manually and see if something wrong happens when i copy it from assets to data folder, but result was the same. I also copied db back to windows and all worked fine.

So my question is: what could be reason of such incompatibility and how i could fix it?

Comment: are you sure it's an sqlite file and not a regular sql file?

Comment: Yea im absolutely sure, file is working great with windows test-version of my app

Comment: what program are you using to view the database in windows?

Comment: SQLite2009 Pro and SQLite Database Browser 2.0, database file starts with "SQLite format 3" and i had no problem using it with my c# application that allows to see SQLite database contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database file i've been using was used during development of database and had quite history of changes. I think either that, version of my file or something completly else was reason of my problems.

Way i fixed it was to create empty database with exact same schema and copy all contents of problematic database file into there. I achieved it using SQLite command line shell.

```
ATTACH DATABASE "D:\dbtest\new.db" AS newdb;
ATTACH DATABASE "D:\dbtest\old.db" AS olddb;
INSERT INTO newdb.android_metadata SELECT * FROM olddb.android_metadata;
INSERT INTO newdb.table1 SELECT * FROM olddb.table1;
... (repeat for each table)
```